# Crystal Reports Calendar error on Server

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports, localhost

My *Crystal Reports* is working well in the localhost but not on the server. When I press the calender in *Crystal Reports*, it shows `Run time Error`.

I'm using *ASP.NET 2.0*, *vb.net*, *SQL 2005*.

How can I configure *Crystal Reports* on the server?

Comment: Please provide more information.  Edit your original post and paste the runtime error.

Answer (score 1):

As dincer80 said, you should deploy Crystal reports properly. [this may help for deployment](http://aspalliance.com/672).

And another [MSDN reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa287928(VS.71).aspx) about topic.

Answer (score 1):

What version of Crystal Reports are you using?  You may be able to download the run time distribution modules from the SAP Crystal site - they have most there.

Answer (score 0):

Have you made sure if it is properly installed on the server?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than xcopy the application you need to create an installer project and include crystal reports as a prerequisite for your application.

Answer (score 0):

The critical details you are missing is what version of Crystal Reports you are using (bundled with Visual Studio versus a full copy of Crystal Reports installed on top of Visual Studio) as well as the runtime error you get.

I suspect you are getting an error about the Crystal assemblies failing to load. Although all these answers are on the right track (deploying runtime) I think you'd do best to read this page: http://resources.businessobjects.com/support/additional_downloads/runtime.asp

It is absolutely critical that you correctly identify the runtime you are using. Remember that Visual Studio 2002/2005/2008/2010 can all use either a bundled edition OR a specific Crystal Reports version. To know which one you are using you should check your .NET project references.